# What does slash mean in macro definitions of C language?

Tags: c, macros

I am new to C programming and I have difficulty to understand what following code does? What does '##' in macro mean, also I don't quite understand how in macro definitions we have for example f1, but without arguments.

My question is different because I also have multiple defines

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a=1, b=2;
#define M(a,b) a ## b(a)
#define a t(f1,t(f1,f2(b)))
#define b(x) t(f2,t(f2,f1(a)))
#define ab(x) a+b(b)
typedef int (*i2i)(int);
int f1(int x) { return (++x); }
int f2(int x) { return (--x); }
int t(i2i f,int x) {return(f(f(x)));}
int main()
{
 printf("%d\n%d", M(a,b), ab(5));
 return (0);
}
```

Comment: This code was clearly not meant to be understood. Of what possible use could it be but entertainment?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Competition :)

Answer (score 1):

The double-octothorpe "`##`" is known as the *token-pasting* operator.  Whatever is on either side of it will be concatenated to form a single string.  It lets you combine an argument with a fixed string, or combine two arguments.  For example:

```
#define ADD_UNDERLINE(x)  _ ## x ## _
ADD_UNDERLINE(foo) // generates: _foo_
```

In your case, you have:

```
#define M(a,b) a ## b(a)
M(foo,bar)   // generates: foobar(foo)
```

---

Regarding your question about `f1`:
The macros use bare function names, but they're used as parameters to the function `t`.  The first parameter of `t` is type `i2i`, which is defined (via typedef) as a pointer to a function.  Using just the bare function name here is generally equivalent to a pointer to that function (note: this isn't standard and would be better written in the macro as "`&f1`").

Comment: We also have x in define, but x doesnt show anywhere after argument section. Where have x gone?

Comment: Ok, never mind, I suppose x is there just to confuse reader, and it really doesn't get used in define at all.

Comment: @user2085124- The argument for a macro isn't necessarily *required* to be used in the macro's expansion.  There's rarely a good reason to do this, though, because it's very confusing for the reader.  The code sample you posted appears to be intentionally difficult to read.

Comment: Yes, it is from competition for students. Anyway, thanks!